# Silverlight windows authentication and running fiddler

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm using WindowsAuthentication in my silverlight application

Here is the setting that I have done in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>



<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""  />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"   />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

it's working fine ,but when ever i run fiddler, the application asks for the username and password! Does any one knows what is the reason behind that.

Thank you,
Naseem

Answer (score 0):

**In fiddler beta 2, there is a option "use proxy credentials".**

Or you can customize the fiddler rule for your development server using:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("www.example.com")){
oSession.bypassGateway = true;
}
```

here is the link how to do it:
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp